# How to copy data from one to table another table with different structure using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to copy data from **Table 1** `TBLUSERFINGER` to a new **Table 2** `TBLUSERFINGER_HORIZONTAL` using `PL/SQL` the second table has different structure.

Table 1 contain `10` rows of data for each `USERID` total number of columns = 6

What I want to do is to rotate this table in horizontal structure so each `USERID` will have `1` row in the `table` instead of having `10` rows for each `USERID` ...by using the new structure at table 2 I will get `42` columns

the primary key in table 2 will be `USERID` ...

I would like to know how to copy the data from Table 1 to table 2 using **PL/SQL procedure** ?? or if anybody have have similar scenario mind to share the link ...I have search some senarious but mine I think it require IF statement or CASE statement .

Table structure

```
SQL> desc TBLUSERFINGER;Name        Null?    Type          
----------- -------- ------------- 
ROW_ID               NUMBER        
USERID      NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(75) 
TEMPLATE             BLOB          
FINGERID    NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(20) 
ISLOCKED             NUMBER(3)     
ISDUPLICATE          NUMBER(3)     
SQL>
```

The new **Tabe 2** structure should be like this consist of 42 columns

```
SQL> desc TBLUSERFINGER_HORIZONTAL;Name                    
----------- -------- --------------------------
ROW_ID                             NUMBER        
USERID(PK)            NOT NULL     NVARCHAR2(75)
FINGER_1_TEMPLATE                  BLOB         
FINGERID_1            NOT NULL     NVARCHAR2(20)   
FINGER_1_ISLOCKED                  NUMBER(3)     
FINGER_1_ISDUPLICATE               NUMBER(3)
FINGER_2_TEMPLATE                  BLOB
FINGERID_2            NOT NULL     NVARCHAR2(20)   
FINGER_2_ISLOCKED                  NUMBER(3)     
FINGER_2_ISDUPLICATE               NUMBER(3)
FINGER_3_TEMPLATE                  BLOB
FINGERID_3            NOT NULL     NVARCHAR2(20)   
FINGER_3_ISLOCKED                  NUMBER(3)     
FINGER_3_ISDUPLICATE               NUMBER(3)
...
...
...
FINGER_10_TEMPLATE                  BLOB
FINGERID_10            NOT NULL     NVARCHAR2(20)   
FINGER_10_ISLOCKED                  NUMBER(3)     
FINGER_10_ISDUPLICATE               NUMBER(3)
SQL>
```

[image]

Comment: is it one-off operation or something you need to do on a schedule

Comment: it's not operation ...or something need to be performed as scheduled ...I already have huge data around 3 million records ...the application start getting slow ...according to my boss making the data in horizontal way will make it faster .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pivot Option. This best suits your requiement. Hope below snippet helps.

```
--Table cretion for test
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
  (
    ROW_ID NUMBER,
    USERID VARCHAR2(75),
    TEMPLATE_DATA BLOB,
    FINGERID    VARCHAR2(20),
    ISLOCKED    NUMBER,
    ISDUPLICATE NUMBER(3)
  );

--Data insertion
INSERT INTO TABLE1
SELECT LEVEL ,
  CASE
    WHEN LEVEL < 11
    THEN 'AV_DUMMY'
    ELSE 'SR_DUMMY'
  END,
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('TEMPLATE_DATA'),
  LEVEL,
  CASE
    WHEN LEVEL < 11
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END,
  CASE
    WHEN LEVEL < 11
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END
FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 21;

--  Data modification as per requirement
UPDATE TABLE1
SET FINGERID   = SUBSTR(FINGERID,2,1)
WHERE FINGERID > 10;


CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
SELECT '1' ROW_ID,
  USERID,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_1_TEMP,
  FINGERID_1_FN FINGERID_1,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_1,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_1,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_2_TEMP,
  FINGERID_2_FN FINGERID_2,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_2,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_2,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_3_TEMP,
  FINGERID_3_FN FINGERID_3,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_3,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_3,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_4_TEMP,
  FINGERID_4_FN FINGERID_4,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_4,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_4,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_5_TEMP,
  FINGERID_5_FN FINGERID_5,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_5,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_5,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_6_TEMP,
  FINGERID_6_FN FINGERID_6,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_6,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_6,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_7_TEMP,
  FINGERID_7_FN FINGERID_7,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_7,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_7,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_8_TEMP,
  FINGERID_8_FN FINGERID_8,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_8,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_8,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_9_TEMP,
  FINGERID_9_FN FINGERID_9,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_9,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_9,
  TEMPLATEDATA FINGERID_10_TEMP,
  FINGERID_10_FN FINGERID_10,
  ISLOCKED ISLOCKED_10,
  ISDUPLICATE ISDUPLICATE_10
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_ID,
    USERID,
    FINGERID,
    ISLOCKED,
    ISDUPLICATE,
    UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(TEMPLATE_DATA)) TEMPLATEDATA
  FROM TABLE1
  ) PIVOT ( MAX(ROW_ID), MAX(FINGERID) FN FOR FINGERID IN (1 AS FINGERID_1,2 AS FINGERID_2,3 AS FINGERID_3,4 AS FINGERID_4,5 AS FINGERID_5,6 AS FINGERID_6,7 AS FINGERID_7,8 AS FINGERID_8,9 AS FINGERID_9,10 AS FINGERID_10) );
```

Comment: thanks I will try it and let you know really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Avraij thanks your script is really usefull but it's not working 100%
..the `ROW_ID` in the new table `TBLUSERFINGER_HORIZONTAL` is not 
increasing by `1` for each new row...my total number of `rows` in table
`TBLUSERFINGER` is `3748486`...after running the script the total number 
of rows in `TBLUSERFINGER_HORIZONTAL` is `3745930` it should decreased to `374631`...
and  the TEMPLATE column in table `TBLUSERFINGER`  is `BLOB` type but in the new table 
is `VARCHAR2(4000)` type  not `BLOB`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first draft to get an idea, the BLOB field will need to jump some more hoops. Hope it helps:

```
      DECLARE

          CURSOR FINGER_cur
          IS
               SELECT employee_id
                 FROM TBLUSERFINGER
             ORDER BY rowid ASC;

         l_FINGER   FINGER_cur%ROWTYPE;

         l_sql varchar2(4000); 
      BEGIN
         OPEN FINGER_cur;

         LOOP
            FETCH FINGER_cur INTO l_FINGER;
            EXIT WHEN FINGER_cur%NOTFOUND;
    if l_finger.ROWID  = 1 then 
    INSERT INTO TBLUSERFINGER_HORIZONTAL (FINGER_1_TEMPLATE,FINGERID_1,FINGER_1_ISLOCKED,FINGER_1_ISDUPLICATE)
    VALUES (l_finger.TEMPLATE,l_finger.FINGERID,l_finger.ISLOCKED,l_finger.ISDUPLICATE)
    WHERE USERID = l_finger.USERID;
    else

    l_sql := 'UPDATE TBLUSERFINGER_HORIZONTAL 
    SET FINGER_'|l_finger.ROWID|'_TEMPLATE = '''||l_finger.FINGER_TEMPLATE||''',
    FINGERID_'|l_finger.ROWID|' = '''|l_finger.FINGERID|''',
    FINGER_'||l_finger.ROWID||'_ISLOCKED = '||l_finger.ISLOCKED||',
    FINGER_'||l_finger.ROW_ID||'_ISDUPLICATE = '||l_finger.ISDUPLICATE||'
    WHERE USERID = '''||l_finger.USERID||''';';

    execute immediate l_sql;
   end if;


         END LOOP;

     CLOSE FINGER_cur;
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks I will work based on your answer and give you feedback :)